# Что такое package apache22-2.2.27?

Tags: php, soap, freebsd

Добрый день!

Хотел установить SOAP из порта (FreeBSD):

```
cd /usr/ports/net/php5-soap
make config-recursive
```

Вижу:

```
===> Setting user-specified options for php5-soap-5.4.26 and dependencies
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
===> Options unchanged
```

Запускаю установку:

```
make install clean
```

Вывод такой:

```
===>  Installing for php5-soap-5.4.26
===>   php5-soap-5.4.26 depends on file: /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h - found
===>   php5-soap-5.4.26 depends on file: /usr/local/lib/php/20100525/session.so - found
===>   php5-soap-5.4.26 depends on shared library: libxml2.so - found
===>  Checking if net/php5-soap already installed
pkg_add: could not find package apache22-2.2.27 !
*** [install-package] Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/net/php5-soap.
```

Что такое этот "package apache22-2.2.27"???

Comment: зачем тебе php на freebsd, если ты не знаешь, что такое package или apache? как ты вообще на freebsd попал?

Comment: package --- скомпилированный бинарник. apache --- вэб сервер. apache22-2.2.27 --- апач версии 2.2.27.

Comment: Наверное надо обновить порты? Старые версии ссылаются на такие же старые версии пакетов, которых уже нет нигде. apache22-2.2.27 - веб-сервер apache версии 22-2.2.27. Можете, кстати, попробовать  собрать и его из своих старых портов, так же как php5-soap.

Answer (score 1):

`apache22-2.2.27` - это порт `apache22` (22 тут значит ветку 2.2.x, так как в портах параллельно поддерживается несколько веток этого ПО) версии `2.2.27`. строго говоря, первые два "регистра" версии ПО (2.2) в строчке apache22-2.2.27  встречаются дважды (как часть имени порта и как его непосредственно версия), что может несколько удивлять.